# Why does using c(data frame1 * data frame2) return a list when data frame1*data frame2 return a data frame

Tags: r, frame

In R when I am multiplying two data frames within a c( ) function I get a list as an output but would like to have a data frame returned how can I do this.

Specifically to test it

> str (c(Diesel_Col_Monthly_Prop_df[-1] * Product_Prop_Mch_df [ , 2]))
>       List of 12
>        $ Jan: num [1:14] 0.0335 0.0335 0.0335 0.0335 0.0335 ...
>        $ Feb: num [1:14] 0.0365 0.0365 0.0365 0.0365 0.0365 ...
>        $ Mar: num [1:14] 0.0581 0.0581 0.0581 0.0581 0.0581 ...
>        $ Apr: num [1:14] 0.0936 0.0936 0.0936 0.0936 0.0936 ...
>        $ May: num [1:14] 0.0783 0.0783 0.0783 0.0783 0.0783 ...
>        $ Jun: num [1:14] 0.0616 0.0616 0.0616 0.0616 0.0616 ...
>        $ Jul: num [1:14] 0.0713 0.0713 0.0713 0.0713 0.0713 ...
>        $ Aug: num [1:14] 0.107 0.107 0.107 0.107 0.107 ...
>        $ Sep: num [1:14] 0.0987 0.0987 0.0987 0.0987 0.0987 ...
>        $ Oct: num [1:14] 0.0654 0.0654 0.0654 0.0654 0.0654 ...
>        $ Nov: num [1:14] 0.034 0.034 0.034 0.034 0.034 ...
>        $ Dec: num [1:14] 0.0326 0.0326 0.0326 0.0326 0.0326 ...

```
> str (Diesel_Col_Monthly_Prop_df [-1] * Product_Prop_Mch_df [ ,2])
'data.frame':   14 obs. of  12 variables:
 $ Jan: num  0.0335 0.0335 0.0335 0.0335 0.0335 ...
 $ Feb: num  0.0365 0.0365 0.0365 0.0365 0.0365 ...
 $ Mar: num  0.0581 0.0581 0.0581 0.0581 0.0581 ...
 $ Apr: num  0.0936 0.0936 0.0936 0.0936 0.0936 ...
 $ May: num  0.0783 0.0783 0.0783 0.0783 0.0783 ...
 $ Jun: num  0.0616 0.0616 0.0616 0.0616 0.0616 ...
 $ Jul: num  0.0713 0.0713 0.0713 0.0713 0.0713 ...
 $ Aug: num  0.107 0.107 0.107 0.107 0.107 ...
 $ Sep: num  0.0987 0.0987 0.0987 0.0987 0.0987 ...
 $ Oct: num  0.0654 0.0654 0.0654 0.0654 0.0654 ...
 $ Nov: num  0.034 0.034 0.034 0.034 0.034 ...
 $ Dec: num  0.0326 0.0326 0.0326 0.0326 0.0326 ...
```

Comment: You are multiplying data frames ? Can you please provide few rows of data and expected outcome ? That'll help us solve this faster.

Comment: Please use `dput` to let folks replicate your data, as is mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example.

Comment: Hi,  Yes I am multiplying two data frames.  The first Diesel_Col_Monthly_df

Answer (score 0):

`c(DF)` where `DF` is a data frame always returns a list and `DF * DF` is a data frame so `c(DF * DF)` returns a list.  If you want a data frame don't use `c`.

Using the builtin data frame `BOD`:

```
> str(BOD)
'data.frame':   6 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Time  : num  1 2 3 4 5 7
 $ demand: num  8.3 10.3 19 16 15.6 19.8
 - attr(*, "reference")= chr "A1.4, p. 270"

> str(BOD * BOD)
'data.frame':   6 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Time  : num  1 4 9 16 25 49
 $ demand: num  68.9 106.1 361 256 243.4 ...

> str(c(BOD))
List of 2
 $ Time  : num [1:6] 1 2 3 4 5 7
 $ demand: num [1:6] 8.3 10.3 19 16 15.6 19.8

> str(c(BOD*BOD))
List of 2
 $ Time  : num [1:6] 1 4 9 16 25 49
 $ demand: num [1:6] 68.9 106.1 361 256 243.4 ...
```

Comment: Thanks,  What should I use in place of c

Comment: You don't need anything in place of `c`.  If you want to multiply two data frames that already gives a data frame.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the help!